# How to say "may I come in" in German?

Tags: meaning

Could this two sentences be right? What I am trying to say is: *May I come in?*

1. Darf ich betreten?
2. Darf ich hereinkommen?

Comment: I can't find an aspect in this question, which is not covered by a dictionary as [here](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=come+in&l=deen&in=ac_en&lf=en).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can say

> Darf ich hereinkommen?

or in spoken German

> Darf ich reinkommen?

Older people may also say

> Darf ich eintreten?

but that is not so common nowadays.

Your first sentence is wrong, because it is always "etwas betreten", like stepping on grass ("Rasen betreten verboten!"). But you could say

> Darf ich **den Raum** betreten? ("May I step into this room?")

or

> Darf ich **den Teppich** betreten? ("May I step onto this carpet?")